# multicast performance with different size of message

Tags: c++, c, sockets, multicast

I wrote a ping pong test program to test the performance of my socket lib, and
I find the multicast performance is constant regardless to the size of the transfer packet. So I am wondering have I done something wrong with the socket, or this is something i should expected?

Here is my test results:

```
buffer size:56 packet size:56 iteration:10000000 RRT/message: 12234ns
buffer size:128 packet size:128 iteration:10000000 RRT/message: 12316ns
buffer size:256 packet size:256 iteration:10000000 RRT/message: 12598ns
buffer size:512 packet size:512 iteration:10000000 RRT/message: 12782ns
buffer size:1024 packet size:1024 iteration:10000000 RRT/message: 17599ns
```

Sections of my code:

```html
mmsghdr* packets;
iovec* iovecs;
....
packets = new mmsghdr[batch_recv_size];
std::memset(packets, 0, sizeof(packets));
iovecs = new iovec[batch_recv_size];
std::memset(iovecs, 0, sizeof(iovecs));
for (int i = 0; i < batch_recv_size; i++)
{
    iovecs[i] =
    {};
    iovecs[i].iov_base = pool.malloc();
    iovecs[i].iov_len = max_msg_size;
    packets[i] =
    {};
    packets[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov = &iovecs[i];
    packets[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
}
....
int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (fd < 0)
{
    error_code = errno;
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to create socket. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code, strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Set reuse address.
if (!asio::socket_util::set_reuseaddr(fd, &error_code))
{
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to set reuse address. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code, strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Bind.
// Do not bind to INADDR_ANY, otherwise you will receive data from two multicast ip with same port.
sockaddr_in listen_sockaddr;
listen_sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
listen_sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(mcast_ip.c_str());
listen_sockaddr.sin_port = htons(mcast_port);
if (bind(fd, (sockaddr*) &listen_sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0)
{
    error_code = errno;
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to bind. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code, strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Set non-blocking.
if (!asio::socket_util::set_nonblock(fd, &error_code))
{
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to set non-blocking. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code, strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Set socket receive buffer size.
socklen_t opt_len = sizeof(socket_recv_buffer_size);
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &socket_recv_buffer_size, opt_len) < 0)
{
    error_code = errno;
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to set socket receive buffer size. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code,
            strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Get the socket receive buffer size.
int recv_buffer_size_set = 0;
if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &recv_buffer_size_set, &opt_len) < 0)
{
    error_code = errno;
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to get socket receive buffer size. ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s.", error_code,
            strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

// Join multicast group.
ip_mreq mreq =
{};
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mcast_ip.c_str());
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(mcast_interface_ip.c_str());
if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
{
    error_code = errno;
    close(fd);
    std::snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Failed to join to multicast address: %s ErrorNo: %d, ErrorText: %s",mcast_interface_ip.c_str(), error_code,
            strerror(error_code));
    if (user_handler.on_error)
    user_handler.on_error(std::string(error));
    return;
}

//When receive signal from epoll, on_event triggered
void on_event(uint32_t events)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int packet_count = recvmmsg(mcast_fd, packets, batch_recv_size, 0, NULL);
        if (packet_count > 0)
        {
            unsigned long long recv_time = date_util::get_nanosecs_since_epoch();
            for (int i = 0; i < packet_count; i++)
            {
                user_handler.on_recv(recv_time, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(iovecs[i].iov_base), iovecs[i].iov_len);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. Performance is likely to be roughly the same until you exceed the path [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) size for the network route between the hosts used in your tests. If they're both on the same ethernet then this size is likely to be around 1500 bytes. Once the PMTU size is exceeded then you will get fragmentation at the IP layer and that will affect performance.

On Linux, use the [tracepath](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tracepath) utility to discover the PTMU between the hosts and adjust your test parameters accordingly.